# How do I upload an ISO to the Hyper-V data store?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I've just installed Windows Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 and I'd like to put some OS ISOs on the data store. How do I do this?

I've configured remote administration so I can connect to the server using Hyper-V Manager, Remote Desktop and Computer Management.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the reason for the downvote...

Comment: I'm not understanding the question (but I didn't downvote it). Is this a full GUI install of Server 2012 R2?

Comment: It is Hyper-V server 2012 R2, which is an appliance-like version of Server 2012 with only Hyper-V. It's roughly equatable to VMWare ESXi.

Comment: @joeqwerty [It's the Hyper-V hypervisor only](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2), not the Windows server OS.  Think like Windows Server Core, but instead of running the Windows OS, you're just running the Hyper-V hypervisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V works a bit differently than ESXi.  You don't create a datastore and upload ISOs to it, [you create a VMM library share and put your ISOs there](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340124.aspx).

This would be done with Virtual Machine Manager, which is the rough equivalent of vSphere in the Hyper-V world.

[How to Add a VMM Library Server or VMM Library Share](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg610579.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to go on the server and create a share. In my case, I ran:

```
net share "Downloads=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads" "/GRANT:EVERYONE,FULL"
```

which is terribly insecure but fine if temporary and on a restricted network.

You can then access the ISOs you push in the Hyper-V Manager settings when you set the CD/DVD-ROM ISO.

Comment: To remove it `net share /delete "Downloads"`

Comment: Also, if you want to access the Hyper-V server's network share `c$` using the credentials for the local administrator account then execute PowerShell command `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" -Type Dword -Value 1`.